# Multiply all the matrices in a nested list together

Tags: r, list, matrix, pipeline

I have a list of 4 matrices

```
A = list(a = matrix(1:4, 2), b = matrix(2:5, 2))

G = list(a = matrix(10:13, 2), b = matrix(5:8, 2))

M_1 = list(a = matrix(10:13, 2), b = matrix(5:8, 2))

M_2 = list(a = matrix(2:5, 2), b = matrix(5:8, 2))

dlist <- pmap(list(A, G, M_1, M_2), list) %>% 
  simplify() %>%
  map(.,
    ~{names(.) <-  c("A",
                     "G",
                     "M_1",
                     "M_2"); .})
```

I used the above pipeline instead of `dlist <- list(A,G,M_1, M2)` because I want to keep the nested lists' names.

I need a list of 4 matrices, each being the product of all the elements within `A`, `G`, `M_1`, `M_2`. The code below gave me a list of 2, `a`, and `b`, in which `a` is the product of all the matrices named `a` across all the four lists (A, G, M_1, M_2); and similarly for `b`.

```
res <- dlist  %>%
  map(., ~{Reduce( "%*%", .)}) 

res
$a
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,] 5519  9859
[2,] 8220 14684

$b
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,] 5866  7970
[2,] 7773 10561
```

I don't seem to find anything similar asked before. How do I fix my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. The command you suggested did not preserve the list names. I need the list names to keep track of the flow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tibble::lst()` creates self-named lists (analogous to `data.frame`).

```r
map(lst(A, G, M_1, M_2), \(x) x[[1]] %*% x[[2]])
```

or slightly more inscrutably

```r
map(lst(A, G, M_1, M_2), lift(`%*%`))
```

(or, of course)

```r
lst(A, G, M_1, M_2) %>% map(lift(`%*%`))
```